# Mystery... Faked Referrer Generates 500 Instead of 404 Error

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

I hope someone can provide some clues.I have begun receiving
regular 500 errors from a page that does not exist.  Without providing
the entire error page, here are the essentials:

```
  [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Internal Server Error: /sample/
```

path/calendar.pl

```
  IOError: request data read error

  'HTTP_REFERER': 'http://mydomain.org/calendar.pl',
  'PATH_INFO': u'/sample/path/calendar.pl',
```

If I visit the page http://mydomain.org/calendar.pl, I get a 404
error, but the error message referencing the same page generates an
internal server (500) error.

QUESTIONS:
Should I be concerned?
Why do I get a 500 error instead of 404 error?
Any suggestions for troubleshooting?

This has been driving me nuts for a few days.  Any help is very
appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change one of the attributes of `request`, which are read-only (or at least, [should be considered to be read-only"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#attributes)). Are you trying to change `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']`?

Answer (score 0):

This is [still an open bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19866) which might be resolved in v. 1.6.

In the meantime, though, you can use [this workaround](http://www.tiwoc.de/blog/2013/03/django-prevent-email-notification-on-suspiciousoperation/) in your settings.py file.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, references tend to get stale over time. Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis (of the workaround) here, keeping the link as a reference.